# Suppress bibliography headings in biblatex' refsection environment

Tags: biblatex

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

You should read \emph{either}

\begin{refsection}
    \nocite{knuth:ct:a}
    \printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\emph{or}

\begin{refsection}
    \nocite{knuth:ct:b}
    \printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I suppress the bibliography headings `References` in cases like this? Or alternatively, what is a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve here, which is to insert one or more bibliography items in a text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can use

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

The better way should be to use

```
\fullcite{key}
```

The cited reference will then also appear in the bibliography.

Comment: Why is `\fullcite` better? It seems to me it would require a lot of manual tweaking in order to make it look like a reference, since it doesn't include normal bibliography settings such as hanging indents.

Comment: If you want the reference to look exactly like in a bibliography then `\printbibliography[heading=none]` inside a `refsection` environment is the easiest solution.  In that case, you maybe want to use `\nocite` also outside of the `refsection` to make sure the reference appears in the main bibliography as well. As `refsection`s cannot be nested, there are situations where you have to use `\fullcite` instead.